# Is there a way to reverse the processing of a specific function?

Tags: python

I've been writing a small "encryption" program for a homework, but although it can encrypt a given String easily, I just cannot figure out how to perform decryption of the resulting string. The encryption function goes as follows:

```
char_set = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','ñ','o','p','r','s','t','u','v','w',
    'x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','Ñ','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U',
    'V','W','X','Y','Z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0',' ','.',',']
char_set.reverse()
cypherText = ''

def encrypt(msg):
    global char_set, cypherText
    shifts = len(msg)**2**2
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(char_set)):
        letter = char_set[i]
        shifted_letter = char_set[(i + shifts) % len(char_set)]
        d[letter] = shifted_letter
    for letter in msg:
        if letter in char_set:
            letter = d[letter]
            cypherText += letter
        else:
            cypherText += letter
    return cypherText
```

Is there a native way to reverse the processing this function is doing, or does any of you have a suggestion on how to "reverse engineer" this code?

Comment: No, there is definitely no way a computer can work out how to undo an arbitrary computation. You need to solve this problem yourself, and then write code implementing your solution. Here's a hint: build the dictionary so the mapping is in the opposite order (i.e. from shifted letters to unshifted letters).

Comment: You don't need to "reverse engineer" something if you have access full access to the original engineering (that is: the source code you posted). It looks like your homework consists on reading and understanding the computation so that you can write the reverse of it yourself.

Comment: I'm not even sure this encryption is reversable. The way you build the `d` dictionary doesn't ensure that the mappings are unique.

Comment: BTW, `len(msg)**2**2` is the same as `len(msg)**4`.

Comment: @James Approximating an inverse function is not the same as computing an inverse function, even if I let you iron out all the differences between a function on strings and a continuous function on real numbers. If you really had a magic box that inverted any function, then you would be able to compute the Riemann zeta function's preimage of 0 when the domain is restricted to exclude trivial zeros and the critical line. Likewise, you would be able to algorithmically decide pretty much any mathematical problem, including the ones which are known to be undecidable.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure why you say the mapping isn't ensured to be unique; the mapping from indices to indices is via `(i + something) % length`, so the mapping from characters to characters is bijective so long as the characters are all distinct.

Comment: @James Also, the fact that it's *possible* for a neural network to approximate a given function doesn't mean that a computer can algorithmically choose a dataset to train that neural network on, and know when to stop training. Suppose the function `lambda a, b, c, n: a**n + b**n - c**n` with the restriction that `a, b, c, n` are positive integers and `n >= 3`, how does the computer decide when to stop looking for inputs where the output is zero? If the training set includes no examples where the output is zero, how will the neural network compute a preimage of zero, or be sure there isn't one?

Comment: @kaya3 You're right, for some reason I thought there was multiplication involved, and that could produce duplicates. This is basically just rotating `char_set`.

Comment: @James You're also equating "function" with computation, but it's generally undecidable whether a given computation computes a given function. For example, if a theorem about natural numbers is false, then the computation which tests that theorem for a given natural number will compute the mathematical function `f(x) = False`, but determining that would require deciding whether the theorem is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the encryption does is to rotate the character mapping by a certain offset, the decryption would only need to rotate the mapping in the opposite direction; that is, change:

```
shifted_letter = char_set[(i + shifts) % len(char_set)]
```

to:

```
shifted_letter = char_set[(i - shifts) % len(char_set)]
```

for the decryption function and it will work:

```
def decrypt(cypherText):
    msg = ''
    shifts = len(cypherText)**2**2
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(char_set)):
        letter = char_set[i]
        shifted_letter = char_set[(i - shifts) % len(char_set)]
        d[letter] = shifted_letter
    for letter in cypherText:
        if letter in char_set:
            letter = d[letter]
            msg += letter
        else:
            msg += letter
    return msg
```

so that:

```
print(decrypt(encrypt('Hello, world!')))
```

outputs:

```
Hello, world!
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/CadetblueMotherlyInverse